# Using ScalaJS js.Object.defineProperty

Tags: scala.js

Using ScalaJS, I need to create a `js.Object` containing a single property whose value is a function, so I've done this:

```
@JSGlobal
class EventPropertyDescriptor(n: Int, rpt: WeatherReportBuilder) extends PropertyDescriptor() {
  this.configurable = true
  this.enumerable   = true
  this.value        = buildSlippyMap("mapDiv" + n, rpt)
  this.writable     = true
  this.get          = null
  this.set          = null
}


var onAfterRenderingHandler = Object.defineProperty(new Object(), "onAfterRendering", new EventPropertyDescriptor(counter, report))
```

Where `buildSlippyMap` returns `Function0[Unit]`

But this won't compile because, as far as I understand, js.PropertyDescriptor has been implemented as a trait, and Scala traits can't directly translated to JavaScript...

How should I proceed here?

Thanks

Chris W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code snippet is that you define `EventPropertyDescriptor` as (native) `@JSGlobal` class. You're literally telling to the compiler: "there is a class named `EventPropertyDescriptor` in JavaScript's global scope, that I did not write, go use that one". In fact, you should be getting plenty of compiler warnings about that snippet.

If `PropertyDescriptor` were a non-native JS trait--which it is in Scala.js 1.x but not in 0.6.x--, you could write:

```scala
val onAfterRenderingHandler = js.Object.defineProperty(
    new js.Object(),
    "onAfterRendering",
    new js.PropertyDescriptor {
      configurable = true
      enumerable = true
      value = buildSlippyMap("mapDiv" + counter, report)
      writable = true
    }))
```

However, since Scala.js 1.x is still in the milestones, and you're probably using 0.6.x, you'll have to use a dirtier route:

```scala
val propDescriptor = js.Dynamic.literal(
    configurable = true,
    enumerable = true,
    value = buildSlippyMap("mapDiv" + counter, report),
    writable = true
).asInstanceOf[js.PropertyDescriptor]
val onAfterRenderingHandler = js.Object.defineProperty(
    new js.Object(),
    "onAfterRendering",
    propDescriptor)
```

See also @gzm0's answer, in particular questioning whether you need `defineProperty` at all.

Comment: Current [documentation](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/1.0.0-M2/scala/scalajs/js/PropertyDescriptor.html) seems to indicate members of  `PropertyDescriptor` are read-only (vals), while they are mutable (vars) in the sources (at least in 2.13.8). Having them writable seems necessary for the Scala.js 1 in this answer to work. Is the documentation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to define the fields in your subclass. Also, it'll need to be a non-native class:

```
class EventPropertyDescriptor(n: Int, rpt: WeatherReportBuilder) 
   extends PropertyDescriptor {
  val configurable = true
  val enumerable = true
  val value = buildSlippyMap("mapDiv" + n, rpt)
  val writable = true
}

var onAfterRenderingHandler = Object.defineProperty(new Object(), 
    "onAfterRendering", new EventPropertyDescriptor(counter, report))
```

Although, couldn't you just do?

```
var onAfterRenderingHandler = new js.Object {
  val onAfterRendering = buildSlippyMap("mapDiv" + counter, report)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see thanks.  That compiles now (still quite new to Scala...)

Comment: Actually, having played around with this option, I've discovered that the property name "onAfterRendering" is created, but JavaScript does not recognise the value returned by `buildSlippyMap` to be a function.  I then get a weird runtime error in the browser.

@sjrd's answer for Scala.js 0.6.x works.